# Windows authentication to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I m using [sql-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-cli) node module to get access to SQL Server. I am able to ping the server and I 'm sure the credentials are correct.

I have two questions about it.

1. How to do Windows authentication through `sql-cli` module? Which parameters do I use for getting Windows authentication?
2. Typically we use `<domain_name>/<user_name>`. When I do the same via command line  its interpreting as `<domain_name><user_name>` without slash in between.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: I don't see any option to connect via windows authentication. This requires you to be pre-authenticated to active directory, which is unlikely on a non windows platform. With regards to slash, the usual approach is to use two slashes to escape it, i.e. `<domain_name>//<user_name>`. In a windows platform you cannot provide windows credentials. It automatically uses your current credentials.

Comment: I don't think its possible to connect to sql-cli using Windows Authentication. I've only been able to connect using SQL Server Authentication: `mssql -s myservername -u sa -p mypassword -d mydbname -e`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication is Windows based (and/or Active Directory Based). I'm sorry but I think you have to use a sql server user to connect.
I had the same problem with freetds to connect from linux and used a SQL Server user.